# Displaylink ryzen 7 pro 5850U Ubuntu 21.04 very slow?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 21.04, displaylink, amdgpu-pro

I tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 but after the install the computer always got stuck on the Lenovo boot screen (probably something with the relatively new cpu I guess?)
After that I tried installing Ubuntu 21.04 and everything seemed to be working fine but there are some things that I have problems with.
I installed displaylink to use my dock, but the external monitor is extremely slow (almost unusable).
I figured it probably had something to do with my amd gpu drivers, but amd only releases their PRO drivers for LTS versions of Ubuntu. I was intending to use the integrated gpu for some hardware accelerated tasks but without these drivers my programs don't even start.
Is there any way to

1. Make the external displaylink screen usable?
2. Install the amdgpupro drivers on 21.04 or install 20.04 LTS on my machine?
   Or both obviously :)

If there is any extra information I should provide or tests I should run, I'm happy to do that.

Comment: Did you boot in EFI mode? Assuming you booted in EFI, about your first issue (non-booting), did you set an EFI System (boot) Partition? The installer would set it as the boot partition. About the issue with DisplayLink, see this and read through: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1875015

Comment: Yes, I set EFI boot partition. Did the exact same install on 20.04 as on 21.04. As stated in the comments from the link you provided the fix isn’t yet ready for amd gpu so the only thing I can do is wait i guess?

Comment: Update: I don’t know if this is helpfull information but when I connect my display directly with hdmi (without the displayport dock) everything works fine.

Comment: hi, can you provide a link to drivers you want to install?